# NServiceBus : Received an empty message

Tags: c#, nservicebus

My NServiceBus is throwing a warning that it received an empty message and hence ignoring it.
But the message is indeed not empty.

My bus configuration

```
Configure.With()
                 .Log4Net()
                 .DefaultBuilder()
                 .XmlSerializer()
                 .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
                 .MsmqTransport()
                     .IsTransactional(true)
                     .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                 .UnicastBus();
```

Here is the message. The xml is correct(I mean that the values and tags of the xml are correct compared to the object that I sent).

```
<Messages>
<Class1>
<Class2>
<QueueAddress>.\\private$\\myerrorqueue</QueueAddress>
<Category>Some string here</Category>
<ExtraInfo> </ExtraInfo>
<Priority> 1 </Priority>
<LookupValue> 1 </LookupValue>
</Class2>
</Class1>
</Messages>
```

The warning

```
2014-06-24 15:45:42,213 [Worker.14] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)
] - Received an empty message - ignoring.
```

I know that deserialization is not possible if there are only readonly properties. My interface doesn't have readonly properties.

```
public interface ISomeInterfaceImplementedByClass1
{
    Class2 class2{ get; set; }
}
```

As mentioned in [NServiceBus - Server is throwing empty message warning to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685797/nservicebus-server-is-throwing-empty-message-warning-to-the-console?lq=1), I made sure to have same configuration for the bus at sender and receiver side but still the problem exists.

What might be the cause?

UPDATE:
If I use JSONSerializer then appropriate handler is being invoked. So it doesn't work with XMLSerializer.

Comment: I assume you're obfuscating your message due to security concerns, but as you have it it's almost unreadable. Could you change it to be a little more representative of the real message? For example, call a string property "StringA" and an int property "IntA" or something like that.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited the xml. Hope its somewhat more readable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason : I was creating an instance of an interface and sending it. XMLSerializer was not serializing interfaces.

Instead of XMLSerializer, I used JSONSerializer and appropriate Handler was invoked.